# queryselector undefined even after checking it with if conditional

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, modal-dialog, alert

I'm learning the basics with Javascript and I'm trying to do a modal that replace an alert, I'm almost done but I have a problem with the querySelector on the button to close it. It returns undefined even if I check it with the if conditional.

```js
function getTemplate(templateName) {
  let template = document.querySelector(templateName);
  return template.innerHTML;
}

function createFragment(htmlStr) {
  let frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  let temp = document.createElement('div');
  temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
  while (temp.firstChild) {
    frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
  }
  return frag;
}

function putTemplate(template) {
  document.body.appendChild(createFragment(template));
}

function openAlert(alertName, btnOpen) {
  let openBtn = document.querySelector(btnOpen);

  openBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    putTemplate(getTemplate(alertName));
  });
}

function closeAlert(alertName, btnClose) {
  let closeBtn = document.querySelector(btnClose);
  if (closeBtn) {
    closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
      let alertWrapper = document.querySelector(alertName);
      alertWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(alertWrapper);
    });
  }
}

function Alert(alertName, btnOpen, btnClose) {
  openAlert(alertName, btnOpen);
  closeAlert(alertName, btnClose);
}

Alert('#alertTemplate', '.activeBtn', '.deactive');
```

And this is the markup:

```
<template id="alertTemplate">
        <div id="alertWrapper">
          <h1></h1>
          <div class="alertBox confirmAlert" role="alert">
            <p></p>
            <button class="closeBtn deactive troll"></button>
            <button class="acceptBtn deactive"></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </template>
``
```

Comment: What's the value of `btnClose` and what's the markup related to those?

Comment: Add html part as well to understand it better.

Comment: @GMaiolo, It's in the `Alert` function call.

Also I edited the question with the markup that's used by the js.

@VaritJPatel

Comment: @Ren. edit your question with proper markup if you can, please

Comment: Done :) added the markup to the question